# Jooq converter from Postgres array to scala list

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a scala case class

```scala
case class MyRecord(
    id: String,
    dimensions: List[String], // postgres text[]
    dimensionCodes: List[Long] // postgres integer[]
)
```

and a Jooq query

```
        JooqBuilder
          .default(conn)
          .select(
            field("id", classOf[String]),
            field("dimensions", classOf[List[String]]),
            field("dimensionCodes", classOf[List[Long]]),
           
          )
          .from(table(MY_TABLE))
        
          .fetchInto(classOf[MyRecord])
          .asScala
          .toList
```

Ofc, it doesn't work since jooq can't map array to scala List.
I'm actively using `org.jooq.Converter` which is quite cool and flexible thing to have. I don't understand how to make it for Postgres array

UPD
What I've tried:

```scala
class JooqArrayConverterOld extends Converter[PgArray, List[Long]]
```

doesn't compile. Got deeper into the code, seems like jooq makes it much-much easier for the user. DB type should be `Array[Object]`

I think I've found a right way to do it.

```
class JooqStringArrayConverter extends Converter[Array[Object], List[String]]

  private val jooqStringArrayConverter = org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.OTHER.getArrayDataType.asConvertedDataType(
    new JooqStringArrayConverter()
  )
```

worked well for
`field("dimensions", jooqStringArrayConverter)` so this case closed.
Still struggling with `List[Long]`

```scala
class JooqLongArrayConverter extends Converter[Array[Object], List[Long]] {
  override def from(databaseObject: Array[Object]): List[Long] =
    Option(databaseObject)
      .map(_.asInstanceOf[Array[Int]]) // Exception!
      .map(_.toList.map(_.toLong))
      .getOrElse(List.empty)

  override def to(userValue: List[Long]): Array[Object] =
    ???

  override def fromType(): Class[Array[Object]] = classOf[Array[Object]]

  override def toType: Class[List[Long]] = classOf[List[Long]]
}
```

throws

```
Error while reading field: dimensionCodes, at JDBC index: 10
...
Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Integer; cannot be cast to class [I ([Ljava.lang.Integer; and [I are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I guess again painful java primitives. Hope we will get rid of them some time in the future.

Comment: What specific issue are you having with the `Converter` API?

Comment: Updated question, almost great success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked worked for me.

```scala
class JooqLongArrayConverter extends Converter[Array[Object], List[Long]] {
  override def from(databaseObject: Array[Object]): List[Long] =
    Option(databaseObject)
      .map(_.map(e => e.asInstanceOf[Int]))
      .map(_.toList.map(_.toLong))
      .getOrElse(List.empty)

  override def to(userValue: List[Long]): Array[Object] =
    ???

  override def fromType(): Class[Array[Object]] = classOf[Array[Object]]

  override def toType: Class[List[Long]] = classOf[List[Long]]
}


  private val jooqLongArrayConverter = org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.OTHER.getArrayDataType.asConvertedDataType(
    new JooqLongArrayConverter()
  )

          .select(
            field("dimensionCodes", jooqLongArrayConverter)
//
).from(table(MY_TABLE))
```

Comment: If you work with `Array[Object]` and `SQLDataType.OTHER`, instead of the actual type of the array, then jOOQ will have less information about the database type to be used for automatic casts, etc. You're not gaining anything from this, I think? Why not use `Array[java.lang.Integer]` and `SQLDataType.INTEGER`, instead?

Comment: This is what I've figured out from source code, what you suggest is much better in terms of type-safety. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Scala type `Array[Int]` corresponds to `int[]` on the JVM (encoded as `[I`). You want it to be `java.lang.Integer[]`, so use `Array[java.lang.Integer]` instead.